# Swing change image with a button

Tags: java, image, swing, button

I have 2 class defined this way :

```
public class Cartes extends JPanel
{
  private BufferedImage image;
  protected int tabC[] = new int[9];
  public int randomC ;

  public Cartes ()
  {

    ..........

    BufferedImage myPicture = null;

    try {
      myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("images/"+randomC+".png"));
    } 
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon( myPicture ));
    add( picLabel );
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null); //
  }
}
```

Note : `randomC` is an integer generated in the constructor allowing me to choose at random an image .

AND

```
public class VueGeo extends JFrame
{
  public Cartes pan = new Cartes();
  private JButton bouton = new JButton("Change");

  public VueGeo()
  {

    ...

    container.add(pan, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    bouton.addActionListener(new BoutonListener ());

    ...

    this.setContentPane(container);

    this.setVisible(true);

  }

  class BoutonListener implements ActionListener
  {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
      ????????
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is I don't know what to put in `actionPerformed` in order to allow me to change image whenever i click on Change . Does someone has an idea please ?

Comment: 1) Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a setter method in Cartes:

```
public void setImage(BufferedImage i)
{ image = i; }
```

Then, in actionPerformed,

```
cartes.setImage( (whatever image you would like) );
cartes.repaint();
```

Comment: (sorry i can't indent) Thanks for your help, but when i click on change, it doesn't change anything T_T, here what i typed in actionPerformed :



    BufferedImage Picture = null;
   try {
    Picture = ImageIO.read(new File("images/8.png"));
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
    pan.setImage( Picture);
    pan.repaint();
    }

Comment: issue solved thanks, i should have just used image instead of myPicture in Cartes.

Comment: ah yes , sorry it is my first time here ^^